# How does the following omp parallel if works?

Tags: c, linux, openmp, openmpi

When I enter i = 1 it outputs:

```
c[0] = 7
c[0] = 7
c[0] = 7
c[0] = 7
c[0] = 7
```

but when i enter i = 0 it outputs:

```
c[1] = 9
c[2] = 11
c[3] = 13
c[4] = 15
c[0] = 7
```

shouldn't the output of i = 0 be the output of i = 1 and vice versa?

````
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ;
    int b[5] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10} ;
    int c[5];
    int tid;
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    #pragma omp parallel if(i)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(5)
            {
                tid = omp_get_thread_num();
                c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
                printf("c[%d] = %d\n", tid, c[tid]);    
            }
    
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks man didnt spot it. my brain is fried

Comment: The output looks fine. `omp_get_thread_num()` returns a logical number of thread in the group. Therefore in first case you can 5 threads each with id 0.

Comment: @tstanisl but if we enter 0, shouldnt it execute serially? like c[0] then c[1] and so on?

Comment: @tstanisl and if we enter 1 the program should create 5 threads and all should execute addition. but the opposite is happening

Comment: The program will split into threads at the second `#pragma omp parallel`. There will be threads each with tid from 0 to 4. It will produce the observed output (up to ordering of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you see is correct (assuming that the variable `tid` has been declared `private` as otherwise you have a race condition here).

Indeed, the first `#pragama omp parallel if(i)` will create a parallel region with an implementation defined number of threads if and only if `i` isn't `0`.
But then, if the parallel region has been created, then the following `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(5)` will be ignored as by default, nested parallelism is disabled.

And if `i` was `0` and the first parallel region wasn't created (no more nested parallelism here), then the second one will indeed be created and 5 threads will be spawned.

In summary, `i` non null prevents the inner parallel region to be created, while `i` null allows it.

Comment: oh now i get it. Thanks alot man <3